# How can I create a rolling mean on a category instead of a float?

Tags: python, pandas, categories, mean, rolling-computation

I have a column in my data frame with a category. I know how to do a rolling mean on a column with float values:

```
df['rolling_mean'] = df.categorycolumn.rolling(10).mean()
```

But I do not have numbers in this column but letters, for example:

```
A
A
A
A
D
D
D
D
D
S
D
D
D
D
D
```

And I want to get rid of the S, so I want to try to make a rolling average so it will be less sensitive for anomalies. Does anyone know how to do this?

Greetings and enjoy the sun (if there is any)!

p.s. Actually I am not looking for the mean but for the mode, the most common category value over a certain window.

So my data frame looks like this:

```
id category
1 A
2 A
3 A
4 A
5 A
6 A
7 S
8 S
9 A
10 A
11 A
12 A
13 A
14 A
15 A
17 A
18 A
19 A
20 A
```

And I wont it to find the mode of a rolling window like 10, so the full column would become only A (and no S)

Comment: please provide the DataFrame constructor of the input and the expected output

Comment: Why? I think I made my question pretty clear this way.

Comment: What is it a `mean` of letters?

Comment: Yes that's a great question. I think I expressed my question wrong. For example a rolling part of 10 in the category column : AAAAASAAAA. It will make: AAAAAAAAAA. Because A occurs the most. I am sorry for being so unclear.

Comment: I am looking for the mode not the mean.

Comment: @SimonDL because if you help us by making it easier to load the data and to understand the expected output, you have more chances of us helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `pd.factorize`:

```
# Detection
s = pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['col1'])[0])
m = s.sub(s.rolling(10, center=True, min_periods=1).median()).abs().ge(1)
print(df[m])

# Output
  col1
9    S
```

**Update**

If you are looking for `mode`, try:

```
value, letter = pd.factorize(df['category'])
df['newcat'] = (pd.Series(value).rolling(10, center=True, min_periods=1)
                  .apply(lambda x: x.mode()).map(pd.Series(letter)))
print(df)

# Output
    id category newcat
0    1        A      A
1    2        A      A
2    3        A      A
3    4        A      A
4    5        A      A
5    6        A      A
6    7        S      A  # HERE
7    8        S      A  # HERE
8    9        A      A
9   10        A      A
10  11        A      A
11  12        A      A
12  13        A      A
13  14        A      A
14  15        A      A
15  17        A      A
16  18        A      A
17  19        A      A
18  20        A      A
```